# Animation starts from wrong position

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am triggering an animation but if i will run it second time before it will end then starts from wrong position.

```
void btnRefreshAnimation()
    {
        float pointY = btnRefreshTable.GetY();
        btnRefreshTable.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        anim = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(btnRefreshTable, "y", pointY + 50.0f, pointY);
        anim.SetDuration(2500);
        anim.SetInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(5f));
        anim.Start();


    }
```

And this is run on Activity destroy

```
if (anim != null)
        {
            anim.Cancel();
            anim.Dispose();
            anim = null;
        }
```

Comment: So, you need to save the original position you want to start the animation

Comment: because you getting the position while animating

Comment: Also i forgot to mention that is child inside another element

Answer (score 0):

And remember if you ever animate (even in code behind) in Xamarin Forms in XAML. You must have an initial setting for the Attribute or it will "pop" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the Y position once while it is not moving, create the animation once, and thus re-use that position:

```
void btnRefreshAnimation()
{
    if (anim == null)
    {
        var startingY = button.GetY();
        anim = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(button, "y", startingY + 50.0f, pointY);
        anim.SetAutoCancel(true);
        anim.SetDuration(2500);
        anim.SetInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(5f));
    }
    anim.Start();
}
```

Note: Be sure to reset (`Dispose` and `null`) the animation upon layout changes or rotations...

Comment: I need to ask if i will not cancel it it will plays my animation till it will end? Or if i will destroy activity it cancels automatically my animation?

Comment: @Dim I do not understand your question

Comment: Do i need to dispose and cancel my animation when activity is destroyed or that's the purpose for SetAutoCancel?

Comment: @Dim Assuming the `ObjectAnimator` is a class level variable of the Activity, then No you do not.

Comment: For a strange reason i have add a Task.Delay(50) before getting the point y and it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187367/discussion-between-dim-and-sushihangover).